# Use background-size on background applied via inline CSS

Tags: html, css, inline-code, background-size

I'm applying a background with an inline style because it needs updated with PHP:

```
<div style="background:url(img.jpg)">
    test
</div>
```

At a certain breakpoint, I need to apply background-size:contain;

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    div {
        background-size:contain;
    }
}
```

Edit- It seems that CSS from a stylesheet does not apply when combined with inline CSS in this case. Is there a solution for that?

Here's a simple jsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/z5r1hwmq/

Comment: So you want the image not repeated just fill up the div once?

Comment: "background-size:100% 100%; background-repeat:no-repeat;"  would that work?

Comment: No, the demo is very simplified. I need background-size to work on a background image that's applied via inline CSS. However the background-size rule must come from the stylesheet.

Comment: This could be the one of the few cases you can use !important ... or make an stronger selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try by adding !important, for example

```
background-size:contain!important;
```

However, this is not the best option. It changes the size, but it would be better if you had real structure that you're using so you can get needed element via parent elements and would be able to do this without adding "!important".

Comment: Ah, yeah you and Danko nailed it. I was looking at it like a bug, rather than just needing stronger selectors. I wonder why the default browser styles would be overriding it in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You can dinamically add/change a class with php to a element instead of inline style.

Also You need to add priority to the css class like this `background-size:contain !important;` otherwise the inline styles have priority.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `background-image` instead of `background` so you don't override all the background options and won't need the `!important` ;)

```
<div style="background-image:url(img.jpg)">
   test
</div>
```

Comment: Very true. I have some extra background options I'm using in my actual application which is why I didn't use background-image, but your suggestion is the better way to go in most cases.

Comment: Should be accepted answer. Been struggeling with css being ignored due to using inline css when using `background: url('')`. By using `background-image: url('')` I can use css without `!important`